# Git: pull from master to topic branch before merging into master?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Assume I have a topic branch `fix-bug-#25` that has diverged from `master` a couple of commits ago:

```
o--o--o master
   \
    o--o--o bug-fix-#25
```

On my third commit in `bug-fix-#25` I fixed the bug and want to merge the branch 
into `master`. Should I checkout master first, merge the topic branch into master

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge bug-fix-#25
```

or should I checkout the topic branch and pull from master, before checking out master and merge with the topic branch?

```
git checkout fix-bug-#25
git pull
git pull origin master
git checkout master
git pull
git merge fix-bug-#25
```

What’s the best way to do this, that minimizes the amount of merge conflicts?

Comment: It may be valuable to make sure your bug fix still works with the new code on `master` that isn't currently in your feature/topic branch, in which case you would do the second method, inserting a "testing" step between `git pull origin master` and `git checkout master`. I don't think you'd reduce the amount of merge conflicts with either method, as they'd be resolved when you merge the branch to `master` (first method) or pull `origin/master` into the branch (second method).

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: Imho you should merge smaller changes into `master` but complete bigger changes on the topic branch.**

---

This is a matter of policy, taste and circumstances.

I don't really like too many merge commits which is why I'd go the first route. (I also `git pull --rebase` because of that but that's another story.) It's true that you should test whether `master` still works with your fix as [ajp15243](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883647/ajp15243) mentions (although that is a matter of policy as well) but that can be done on `master` as well. If your fix has small problems, you can reset to before the merge, fix the branch and merge again.

However, if the fix has big problems, e.g., because `master` has had a lot of changes introduced while you were on your topic branch, and requires a lot of work/commits to be fixed, I'd merge `master` into the topic branch first. That helps keep `master` clean.